# Uploaded image to GCP Storage but cannot view iamge using public URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, file-upload, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload an image to GCP storage using PUT-signed URL with Node.js as show [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-generate-upload-signed-url-v4#storage_generate_upload_signed_url_v4-nodejs).

I used axios to call the PUT-signed URL string with the data image and the upload seemed to have been successful. **When I go to the GCP Storage Console to view the public URL, it fails to display in browser** (it automatically downloads it and when I try to view the downloaded content, it is corrupted and won't open).

However, if I use the GCP Storage Console to upload the image directly, I can view the image using the public URL directly in the browser.

**What I tried**:

Getting PUT-signed URL from server-side:

```
import { Storage } from "@google-cloud/storage";

const storage = new Storage({
    projectId: GCP_PROJECT_ID,
    credentials: {
      client_email: GCP_CLIENT_EMAIL,
      private_key: getFormattedGCPPrivateKey(GCP_PRIVATE_KEY),
    },
  });

const gcpFilePath = "path/to/file.jpeg";
const filePath = storage.bucket("test_bucket").file(gcpFilePath);
const [putUrlImage] = await filePath.getSignedUrl({
    version: "v4",
    action: "write",
    expires: Date.now() + 1000 * 30, // 30 seconds
    contentType: "application/octet-stream",
  });
```

Uploading image from frontend:

```
const imageAsBlob = "..." // looks like: blob:http://localhost:3000/867eb7e4-064d-4092-85ea-90ceb1160a39

const imageAsBase64 = Buffer.from(
    imageAsBlob.replace(/^data:image\/(png|gif|jpeg);base64,/, ""),
    "base64"
  )

const imageData = 
await axios.put(putUrlImage, imageAsBase64, {
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream" },
   });
```

**What I expect**:

I am expecting the image to be viewable in the browser through the public URL that GCP Storage provides.

I am not sure if the issue is on the PUT-signed URL side or the image data formatting side.

Comment: Have you tried to upload the image with the header image/jpeg for JPEG type images? if not then try to upload new image with this header

Answer (score 1):

@rajat comment helped. Also, I had to change the `imageAsBlob` to a base64 before replacing `/^data:image\/(png|gif|jpeg);base64,/, ""`. Then it worked!